# minizip append to file

Tags: c++, append, zlib, zip

I'm using Zlib's Minizip program. I am trying to add files to a current zip file. I found that I can append the zip file by using the function:

extern zipFile ZEXPORT zipOpen64 OF((const void *pathname, int append));

with append set to 2. However this does not overwrite files inside the zip instead it just keeps adding files to the end of the zip whether they already exist or not. Is there any way to fix this? I would like to have the option to replace only older files and/or overwrite all files.

Comment: As a basic measure, you could cache the zip's file entry names. When you try and add a new file to the zip, you can see if its filename can be found in the cache, only adding the file if filename not found. Obviously you need to update the cache each time a new file is actually added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minizip library does not currently support anything other than adding files to a zip archive. It does not support deleting or updating files in an archive either.

This quote from the [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) website may help you:

> Ivan A. Krestinin wrote a [small example](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/del.cpp) of how delete a file from zip archive...

You can combine a delete operation with an add operation to achieve in-archive file replacement. The downside to the example code above is that it requires the creation of a temporary zip file on disk.

Comment: Thanks so much for you're help I was able to go off the example and get my program to add files correctly.

Comment: In version 2 of the library, it is possible to remove an entry and then add a new one.